# Slick Carousel - How To Change Default Buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, carousel

I'm working with [Slick Carousel](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) for the first time. The project i'm currently working on needs most of the files loaded through a CDN. How can i replace the default buttons for "Next" and "Previous" that's loaded through their hosted Jquery?

As of now it's just a button with Text, i'd like to replace it with a FontAwesome icon of arrows.

```
<h1> One Slider At a Time </h1>
<div class="slider">
    <div><h3>1</h3></div>
    <div><h3>2</h3></div>
    <div><h3>3</h3></div>
  </div>
```

Here is my [Demo](http://codepen.io/stinkytofu3311/pen/JGbwOV)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use CSS to specify the `content` of `.slick-prev::before` and `.slick-next::before`:

```
.slick-prev::before {
  content: "<";
}
.slick-next::before {
  content: ">";
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ryanpcmcquen/z6qoz1mh/

If you want to use FontAwesome just [load that in](https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/get-started/) and specify the unicode characters as content, for example:

```
.slick-prev::before, .slick-next::before {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
}
.slick-prev::before {
  /* fa-arrow-circle-left */
  content: "\f0a8";
}
.slick-next::before {
  /* fa-arrow-circle-right */
  content: "\f0a9";
}
```

[image: FontAwesome Unicode reference]

Comment: Thanks for the code example. Could you show me a working example with the font-awesome icons as replacements for ">". Every time i try to add the  icons it decides to not load anything.

Comment: @StinkyTofu my example shows exact CSS you can use for FontAwesome characters. Make sure you have FontAwesome loaded in. Please show an example of the code you are having troubles with and we can debug more.

Comment: Thanks Ryan. Sorry for the long wait for a reply. You were right. I was just having some external file issues with linking the correct style sheet. Got it working! Thanks a bunch.